# Representing zero as a rational number

Tags: rational-numbers

How to represent 0 as rational number?

$0/0$ is not legitimate, $0/\text{const}$ should be good enough, but what is the right value of const? $0/1$ works for a lot of computational cases, but only on intuitive.

Comment: $\frac{0}{a}=0$ for *any* $a\neq 0$, and a number doesn't need to be *represented* in some way to be a rational number. $0\in\mathbb{Q}$ since $0\in\mathbb{N}$, for instance.

Comment: Rational numbers are equivalence classes of pairs of integers, so the class of $(0, k)$ suffices for any integer $k \neq 0$

Comment: "In mathematics, a [rational number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) is any number that can be **expressed** [i.e. represented] as the quotient or fraction $\dfrac p q$ of two integers, a numerator $p$ and a non-zero denominator $q$. Since $q$ may be equal to $1$, every integer is a rational number. "

Comment: And I thought that $0/1$ equalled $0$; not just that it works for a lot of computational cases. I can't imagine a "computational case" where it didn't work.

Comment: 0 *is* a rational number. Why do you want to write it any other way?

Comment: @almagest I think the question meant: How to express zero to emphasise it's rationality?

Comment: You can represent the element $0$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ as whatever you want: a color, a figure, a name, a letter, a sound, etc. It's up to your own fantasy.

Comment: If you want a single valued *function* $f:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ rather than to an equivalence class, then a useful function is $f(q)=(n,m)$ where $m$ is the smallest positive integer with $n=mq$ being an integer, but there are many other such functions.  It is common to write $q$ as $\frac{n}{m}$ and you would then write the rational *zero* as $\frac{0}{1}$ as there is no positive integer smaller than $1$

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no single right value. The rational number $0$ can be represented as the quotient of an integer by a non-zero integer in infinitely many ways: $0=\frac 0d$ ($d\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$). Choosing $d=1$ is a natural choice: every rational number can be represented in one and only one way as $\frac nd$ with $n\in\mathbb Z$, $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\gcd(n,d)=1$. In the case of $0$, that representation is $\frac01$.

Comment: There is no "right" value?  Or there is no "single right" value?

Comment: @RandallStewart I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hello! [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4196526) (which in my opinion is a sincere inquiry) is at risk of deletion. The problem is that the linked duplicates are bad [as JMoravitz and I agreed](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8707359), but this wasn't the asker's fault, so could you please edit the duplicate list to add the two links JMoravitz gave in a comment under the question and remove the original, so that it is reasonably justifiable to keep the question (closed as duplicate rather than deleted)? Thanks!

Comment: @user21820 Done.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 15):

What is wrong with 
$$ \cdots=\frac{0}{-2}=\frac{0}{-1}=0=\frac{0}{1}=\frac{0}{2}=\frac{0}{3}=\cdots \ ?$$
You have an  infinity of perfectly defined representations...

Comment: Yes.  And in fact for other rationals you also have infinitely many representations.  $$\dots =\frac{-14}{-4} = \frac{-7}{-2} = \frac{7}{2} = \frac{14}{4}=\dots$$

Comment: $$
\frac{0}{-6} = \frac{-6}{-6} * \frac{0}{1}
$$

Answer (score 7):

$0/1$ is generally considered to be the canonical form. This is important for the definition of the "rational ruler" or modified Dirichlet function:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in \Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q} \\
                        1/q & x = p/q \mbox{ in lowest terms}\end{cases}$$

and I'm sure in many other situations too.

Comment: If you're referring to [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), that actually takes the value $1/q$ instead of $q$ for rational $x$. But a nice example nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, good catch!

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have mentioned, there are many equivalent representations of $0$ in the rational numbers.

A formal way to define rational numbers is the following:

Consider the set -
$$S = \{ (x,y) \in \textbf{Z} \times \textbf{Z} \quad |\quad y \neq 0\}  . $$

The each element $q$ of the rational numbers **Q** is an equivalence class $\bar{s} \in S/\equiv_{\sim}$ under the equivalence relation:
$$(a,b)\sim (c,d) \iff ad = bc$$
Or equivalently in **Q**:
$$ad = bc\iff \frac{a}{b}= \frac{c}{d}$$
Since $0 \cdot b = 0 \cdot d = 0$ for any $d, c \in \textbf{Z}$, we can represent $0 \in \textbf{Q} $ as $(0,x)$ for any $x \in \textbf{Z}-\{0\}$.

You can do this procedure for any integral domain $R$, and it represents the field of fractions of $R$, denoted commonly as $Quot(R)$.